# Altium: How do I flip/mirror components? X and Y don't work

Tags: pcb, altium

So this seem like a simple question, but I'm trying to flip components in the schematic editor. If I select a component then use the keyboard shortcut X or Y, it brings up a menu and does not slip the component as desired. Edit --> Move --> Flip... also does not work. Suggestions? Thanks

Edit: I should have mentioned that I would like to flip groups of components as well as net labels. With net labels the connection point is on the bottom left, but would like to have it on the bottom right such that I can connect it to wires aligned right.

Answer (score 54):

You have to press X or Y key *while you're holding the left-click mouse button pressed* on the component and it will flip.

To be more explicit: Left-click on the component you want to flip, *keep the mouse button pressed* (like when you want to move a component with the mouse) and press X or Y key to flip.

Comment: That's originally what I thought I should do, but alas it doesn't work. When moving the component, X and Y bring up menus. For X, the popup menu has options such as Inside Area, Outside Area, etc. I also noticed that when placing component, pressure tab (should option up properties menu) doesn't work, so maybe there's a problem with my install. I think I'll attempt to re-install and see if that helps.

Comment: @user18482 That's strange. I only get the menu you're talking about (Inside Area, Outside Area etc.) when I select the component (left click on that component) and *press X/Y without still holding the left mouse button pressed*.

Comment: Well, so interestingly enough, I tried a different version of Altium on a different computer, and sure enough X and Y work fine. I'm then forced to conclude my install of Altium is indeed hooped. Thanks for the help regardless.

Comment: @m.Alin How does one flips, for instance, 3 selected components?

Comment: ChatGPT told me this can't be done but clearly the X and Y keys work!

Answer (score 6):

For me, with a group of components, tracks and copper pours selected, moving and typing "L" flips the lot to the other side.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click component -> properties -> check the "Mirror" checkbox (it's in the lower left-ish corner).

To invert, rotate the component 180°, and mirror it.

[image]

---

**Edit:**

Re - Mirroring a group of components and wires: Unfortunately, I have not found a way to successfuly do this either.

Re - Net-labels: Altium doesn't support much flexibility in the way of net-labels, and justifiably so, I think. Net labels are grossly overused as it is.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this option for single components, however it won't work for a group of components/wires/etc or net labels.

Comment: @user18482 - In that case, I think you're out of luck. I haven't found any way to mirror groups of components either.

Answer (score 3):

Found that to mirror several components(at least in schlib), you must select all components, start dragging them, then hit "x".
Altium Designer 14.2

Comment: Thanks for including the version! +1

Comment: It also works for AD 10!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

My X and Y shortcuts weren't set and I had a fresh install. Rather than reinstall you can easily edit the shortcut keys by doing the following:

1. Go to the top menu and navigate to Edit>>Move
2. hold ctrl and left click the option you want to add a shortcut for.
3. In the pop up window, you can enter a key in the Shortcuts section.
   [image]
4. Now you should have access to flip the component via the shortcut key you just set up.
5. Note: you still need to hold left click on the symbol then flip it.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the suggestions above to no avail.
But I did discover that when I clicked "View->Desktop Layouts->Default", the flip x and y started working again.

Comment: That has saved me! Thank you! It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems  like the op had an install problem. I am a long time Altium user and one day X,Y (and even TAB) stopped working as expected.  Fearing a full re-install was at hand, it turned out to be enough to run the installer (Add or Remove Programs, right click Alitum, uninstall) and select "Remove Preferences".  This fixed the inoperative X,Y, and TAB shortcuts for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked for me too:
Tools > Preferences > System > View > Desktop > Reset